# Reading multiple lines of S3 object at once

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is there anyway s3 object can be read in batch of lines. Instead on reading 1 line at time, can I read n lines at a time.

I can use a range of bytes from an object but it will not be a full line and I won't be able to know the when a line is ending.

```
GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key).withRange(startRange,endRange);
```

I need to process N files each of 1GB in size using java. All files resides in S3.